# What word to use to refer to a manager at a gym/drug store?

Tags: pragmatics

According to JMDict there are so many words for a [manager](http://tangorin.com/general/manager) depending on the context. Can someone provide clarification on the context of each term? What is the most appropriate term for a gym manager or a drug store manager? Is the borrowed term マネージャー widely accepted?

> マネージャー
>
> 責任者
>
> 管理者
>
> 支店長
>
> 経営者
>
> 支配人
>
> 店長
>
> 社長
>
> 課長
>
> 主管
>
> 主幹
>
> 主事
>
> 総務
>
> 監事
>
> 元締
>
> 世話人
>
> 世話役

Comment: What is the job description of that "manager"?

Comment: I am not sure, he seems like a manager of a specific gym location but he may manage other locations too.

Comment: Is it really _the_ boss of the place? If not (e. g. just someone in charge), then maybe just 係員?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say `マネージャー (Manager)` or `店長 (Store Manager)`. All the other words don't quite fit (except `支店長 (Branch Store Manager)` or possibly `課長 (Department Manager)`).
Basically the list contains lots of various job titles (think "VP", "Head of X", "Chairman" etc).